# sed/gsed on MacOS Catalina not working as expected with star

Tags: macos, sed

I tried the following:

```
# echo "12MB" | sed -e 's/[bm]\*//i'
12MB
# echo "12MB" | sed -e 's/[bm]\+//i'
12
```

I was expecting both to produce the same output (greedy match), but the one with the star does not. I tried also with gsed, but it was the same result.
When I tried using `-E # for extended re` neither of the two forms works.
An ubuntu docker container also behaves the same way.

Can someone help me understand why is that?

Comment: @kisch answer below explains a lot and is very helpful, However I am still puzzled why the escaped plus sign is not treated the same as the escaped asterisk (it works in the case of the escaped plus sign).

Comment: sed basic regexp syntax is a bit confusing. The escaped plus is the regexp repetition operator meaning "matches one or more times". In this case, the pattern matches at the 'M' in your string, and with one repetition extending to 'B'. The escaped asterisk is a literal asterisk, so that the pattern can't match at all in your string.

Answer (score 2):

First, in sed "basic" regexp patterns `*` is for repetition, `\*` is a literal asterisk. So your example would be

```
# echo "12MB" | sed -e 's/[bm]*//i'
12MB
```

... which still doesn't produce your expected output.

The reason becomes apparent when you use a visible replacement:

```
# echo "12MB" | sed -e 's/[bm]*/!!!/i'
!!!12MB
```

The pattern matches right at the start of the string, for a repetition count of zero. After one match, replacement stops.

So you really want one or more repetitions, like in your working example.